# javascript ошибка динамического обрботчика

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, веб-программирование, chrome-extension

Всем привет. Пождскажите плс, ишу плагин для Хрома выполянет поиск по странице, поскольку инлайновые скрипты нельзя, вешаю динамически обарботчик:

```
document.getElementById('btn-text-to-find').addEventListener('click',FindOnPage('text-to-find'));
```

Форма поиска:

```
> <input type="text" id="text-to-find" placeholder="поиск">  <input
> type="button"  value="найти" id="btn-text-to-find" />
```

скрипт поиска:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var lastResFind=""; // последний удачный результат
var copy_page=""; // копия страницы в ихсодном виде
document.getElementById('btn-text-to-find').addEventListener('click',FindOnPage('text-to-find'));
function TrimStr(s) {
     s = s.replace( /^\s+/g, '');
  return s.replace( /\s+$/g, '');
}
function FindOnPage(inputId) {//ищет текст на странице, в параметр передается ID поля для ввода
  var obj = document.getElementById('btn-text-to-find').addEventListener('click',FindOnPage('text-to-find'))
  var textToFind;

  if (obj) 
  {
    textToFind = TrimStr(obj.value);//обрезаем пробелы
  } 





  if(copy_page.length>0)
        document.body.innerHTML=copy_page;
  else copy_page=document.body.innerHTML;


  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(eval("/name="+lastResFind+"/gi")," ");//стираем предыдущие якори для скрола
  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(eval("/"+textToFind+"/gi"),"<a name="+textToFind+" style='background:yellow'>"+textToFind+"</a>"); //Заменяем найденный текст ссылками с якорем;
  lastResFind=textToFind; // сохраняем фразу для поиска, чтобы в дальнейшем по ней стереть все ссылки
  window.location = '#'+textToFind;//перемещаем скрол к последнему найденному совпадению
 } 
</script>
```

в консоль падает ошибка:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at index.html:6
```

line6:

```
document.getElementById('btn-text-to-find').addEventListener('click',FindOnPage('text-to-find'));
```

что я делаю не так?

Comment: Скрипт стоит до или после формы?

Comment: он в отдельном файле, это же плагин для хрома, из html подключается  обработчик,а  из обработчика сам  файл скирпт:
`<script src="popup.js"></script>`
popup:
`document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function (){
 chrome.tabs.executeScript( {"file": "s.js"});
});`

Comment: document.getElementById('btn-text-to-find') - null. Скрипт выполняется до того как создался DOM. оберните в window.onload и все будет прекрасно

Comment: @JurijJazdanov если верить комментарию выше, он обёрнут в DOMContentLoaded, а DOM в это время уже создан

Comment: @andreymal можете подсказхать как синтаксически, только начал изучать JS

Answer (score 0):

Popup расширения - это отдельная страница, которая с вкладками может общатся единственным способом - через content_script.

Вам нужно сделать как то так:

**content_script.js:**

```
function FindOnPage(text) {
    ...
    ...
    window.location = '#'+textToFind;//перемещаем скрол к последнему найденному совпадению
}
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    FindOnPage(request.textToFind);
});
```

**popup.js:**

```
document.getElementById('btn-text-to-find').addEventListener('click',e => {
    textToFind = obj.value.trim();
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, tab => {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {textToFind}, function sendResponse(response){
            // Это callback, который можно вызвать из content_script
        });
    });
});
```